# What does tr("\302\261") mean in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I was following Qt Calculator example from http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-calculator-example.html.
I encountered the code below.

```
for (int i = 0; i < NumDigitButtons; ++i) {
    digitButtons[i] = createButton(QString::number(i), SLOT(digitClicked()));
}

Button *pointButton = createButton(tr("."), SLOT(pointClicked()));
Button *changeSignButton = createButton(tr("\302\261"), SLOT(changeSignClicked()));

Button *backspaceButton = createButton(tr("Backspace"), SLOT(backspaceClicked()));
Button *clearButton = createButton(tr("Clear"), SLOT(clear()));
Button *clearAllButton = createButton(tr("Clear All"), SLOT(clearAll()));

Button *clearMemoryButton = createButton(tr("MC"), SLOT(clearMemory()));
Button *readMemoryButton = createButton(tr("MR"), SLOT(readMemory()));
Button *setMemoryButton = createButton(tr("MS"), SLOT(setMemory()));
Button *addToMemoryButton = createButton(tr("M+"), SLOT(addToMemory()));

Button *divisionButton = createButton(tr("\303\267"), SLOT(multiplicativeOperatorClicked()));
Button *timesButton = createButton(tr("\303\227"), SLOT(multiplicativeOperatorClicked()));
Button *minusButton = createButton(tr("-"), SLOT(additiveOperatorClicked()));
Button *plusButton = createButton(tr("+"), SLOT(additiveOperatorClicked()));

Button *squareRootButton = createButton(tr("Sqrt"), SLOT(unaryOperatorClicked()));
Button *powerButton = createButton(tr("x\302\262"), SLOT(unaryOperatorClicked()));
Button *reciprocalButton = createButton(tr("1/x"), SLOT(unaryOperatorClicked()));
Button *equalButton = createButton(tr("="), SLOT(equalClicked()));
```

However, I couldn't understand what do `tr("\302\261")` ,`tr("\303\267")`, `tr("x\302\262")`mean from the lines below.

```
Button *changeSignButton = createButton(tr("\302\261"), SLOT(changeSignClicked()));
Button *divisionButton = createButton(tr("\303\267"), SLOT(multiplicativeOperatorClicked()));
Button *powerButton = createButton(tr("x\302\262"), SLOT(unaryOperatorClicked()));
```

When I removed `\303\267`, I found ÷ symbol disappears. So I guess it is somehow related to division button.

I have no idea how \303\267 can be related to division. I searched Qt documentation page, and found nothing.

My question is:

What do `tr("\302\261")` ,`tr("\303\267")`, and `tr("x\302\262")` mean in this example?

Comment: In C++, a backslash followed by 1-3 digits is an octal char code. [Rules for C++ string literals escape character](//stackoverflow.com/q/10220401)

Comment: `\303\267 = 195 183 dec`. Which, using UTF-8 encoding is the division sign. See: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=dec

Comment: `tr()` is a function that marks a string for international translation. At runtime, the input string will be translated to an appropriate language, based on translations configured in the Qt Linguist tool

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

`tr()` function is used for (optional) translation of given string to another languages. From [this answer available on Qt forum](https://forum.qt.io/post/151945):

> If you want your application to have multiple language support, wrap every user-visible string in your code inside a tr() function. Then Qt will use the appropriate translated string in a different language environment. Of course Qt won't actually translate for you, you (or your translator guy) have to do that with QtLinguist.

The strings passed to `tr()` function are octal codes for UTF-8 characters. As you have noticed, `\303\267` is `÷`. `\302\261` is `±`, `x\302\262` means `x` to power of two (`x` followed by superscript two character).

Comment: Use 'QObject::tr()' outside of QOBJECT classes.